# how can I add new variable to mobile-node.h

Tags: simulation, sensors, wireless, ns2

I want to add variable to mobile node class in Ns2; which this variable get initial value in TCL.

For each mobile node we assign a special value to this variable. How can i add this variable to mobile node class?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please read [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Add some more info!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your ns2 directory, and open `mobilenode.h` first.
    For
   example if you have ns-2.35, go to
   `ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/common/` and open it from here.
2. Find the line that says :

   `class MobileNode : public Node`

and go to the last line of the `public:` that may look like `MobileNode* prevX_;` and add your variable here.
Example :

```
         /* For list-keeper */
         MobileNode* nextX_;
         MobileNode* prevX_;

         // My variables
         int32_t NodeQueue;

protected:
```

3. Now to give them an initial value, you can open the file `mobilenode.cc` and fine the constructor of class `mobilenode` that may look like `MobileNode::MobileNode(void) :` and simply give your variable an initial value...
   Example :

   /* ======================================================================
      Mobile Node
      ======================================================================                */

`MobileNode::MobileNode(void) :
        pos_handle_(this)
    {
        X_ = Y_ = Z_ = speed_ = 0.0;
        dX_ = dY_ = dZ_ = 0.0;
        destX_ = destY_ = 0.0;`

```
    random_motion_ = 0;
    base_stn_ = -1;
    T_ = 0;

    log_target_ = 0;
    next_ = 0;
    radius_ = 0;

    position_update_interval_ = MN_POSITION_UPDATE_INTERVAL;
    position_update_time_ = 0.0;


    LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&nodehead, this, link_);   // node list
    LIST_INIT(&ifhead_);                // interface list
    bind("X_", &X_);
    bind("Y_", &Y_);
    bind("Z_", &Z_);
    bind("speed_", &speed_);

    NodeQueue = 0; // Initial value

}
```

And then you need to `cd` in your ns2 directory from terminal and type `make` and click 'Enter'.